# Siddhi :How to check wether a event satisfied a condition for a specified period of time in a batch window

Tags: siddhi

In Siddhi i was trying to write a query that will check for a event condition to be satisfied  for a specified period of time.
following is the requirement:
   for a stream of events with temperature, i need temperature to be always greater than 20 for specified period of time to push it to output stream, using a batch time of 5 mins

Query i used was:

```
@Plan:name('TestExecutionPlan')

@PrimaryKey('sensorId')
define table stable1 (sensorId string, temperature float,count long);
define table stable2 (sensorId string, temperature float,count long);
define stream sensorStream (sensorId string, temperature float);

from sensorStream[sensorId=="tempID1"]#window.timeBatch (1 sec)
select timestamp() as messageID,sensorId ,temperature,count() as count
insert into test1;

@info(name = 'query1') 
from sensorStream[sensorId=="tempID1"]#window.timeBatch (1 sec)
select sensorId ,temperature,count() as count
insert into stable1;

from   sensorStream[sensorId=="tempID1" and temperature>20 ]#window.timeBatch (1 sec)
select  timestamp()  as messageID, sensorId as sensorId, temperature as temperature, count() as count
insert into test2;



from stable1 join test2  on test2.count==stable1.count
select test2.sensorId ,test2.temperature,test2.count
insert into finalStream;
```

For Event stream

```
sensorStream=[tempID1,190.8]
delay(500)
sensorStream=[tempID1,100]
delay(500)
sensorStream=[tempID1,38.8]
delay(200)
sensorStream=[tempID1,15.8]
delay(100)
sensorStream=[tempID1,45.8]
delay(700)
sensorStream=[tempID1,8.8]
delay(500)
sensorStream=[tempID1,18.8]
delay(500)
sensorStream=[tempID1,34.8]
delay(500)
sensorStream=[tempID1,18.8]
delay(500)
sensorStream=[tempID1,18.8]
delay(500)
sensorStream=[tempID1,18.8]
delay(500)
sensorStream=[tempID1,18.8]
delay(500)
sensorStream=[tempID1,18.8]
delay(500)

sensorStream=[tempID1,18.8]
delay(500)
sensorStream=[tempID1,18.8]
delay(500)
```

In Above query i get the count for a specific tagId for timebatch 1 second and then store it in table **stable1**.
and also get count for specific tagId with condition(>20) for time batch 1 second. Then i apply join on both of them to check for matched . So the Issue over here is since there is no Id on which i can join the two, join is not happening properly.

can any one guide me on how to add timestamp to output so that i can join on the same , also let me know if there is any easier way of doing this.

Comment: Is there a need for siddhi extension to be included for this

Answer (score 0):

I should have used **sequence**  for this

the query that resolved the issue is:

```
@info(name = 'query2') 
from e1=sensorStream[sensorId=="tempID1" and temperature>20],e2=out1[sensorId=="tempID1" and temperature>20] within 1 sec
select e1.sensorId,e1.temperature
insert into outstream;
```